# PayPal Windows 8 Checkout SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, paypal

I was reading the documentation about the PayPal Windows 8 Checkout SDK for **Windows Phone 8** on:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/ht_win8xo-examples/

Now, I have three questions:

1) Does the API simply redirect the buyer to PayPal's web page on a button click, from where the buyer can log-into his account using his PayPal username and password and authorize the transaction?

2) If the answer to question 1 is no, does the API make use of the browser control?

3) If the API does NOT make use of the browser control, where do you specify the buyer's PayPal account in the code (see second link)?  The code on the page pointed to by the second link only specifies the merchant's PayPal account.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes to question #1.
2. Not sure if the browser related answer was what
   you were expecting: User will be redirected to either the mobile or
   desktop friendly site for them to authorize the transaction. If you
   are looking for something more specific related to some browser
   control please comment back and we can clarify further.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have another question.  I have developed a mobile payment system for Windows Phone.  Is there an API which invokes the PayPal mobile app on the Windows Phone device (if it is installed) and lets the user pay for the transaction using the PayPal mobile app?

Comment: To help you understand better, the developed mobile payment system lets the buyer enter some credit card details inside it and then pay for the transaction using his credit card.  I was thinking of adding another feature which allows the user to pay using his PayPal account.  Unfortunately, one of the prerequisites of the project is that the developed mobile payment system does not make use of the browser at all.  That's why I asked whether the PayPal Windows 8 Checkout SDK makes use of the browser in my question.

Comment: For answering 1st question: Nope not that I am aware of. But I am going to discuss with my team and we will update back if we have some guidance for you. For 2nd question, we do have some plans of doing something similar but not sure of when you have your timelines in mind. Would you mind updating your timelines as a comment. Suggest to open an issue here so that we can track back : https://github.com/paypal/Windows8SDK/issues?page=1&state=open

Answer (score 0):

if you simply need to process credit card payments you can also have a closer look at [my Windows 8 port](https://milsapp.com/blog/processing-credit-card-payments-on-mac-os-x-and-windows-8) of Braintree Payment's Windows Phone SDK.